# overflow Button cannot change into the add icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow

I want to display the search icon and add icon in my actionbar, and the add icon has the function of overflow button, and the menu item has the icon.

but I have a issue:the overflow button's icon cannot changge into the add icon,and the menu item hasn't the icon.

this is my styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:src">@mipmap/actionbar_add_icon</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

`
this is my menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/actionbar_search_icon"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_group_chat"
    android:icon="@mipmap/menu_group_chat_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_group_chat"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_add_friend"
    android:icon="@mipmap/menu_add_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_friend"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_scan"
    android:icon="@mipmap/menu_scan_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_scan"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_receive_money"
    android:icon="@mipmap/menu_receive_money"
    android:title="@string/menu_receive_money"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_feedback"
    android:icon="@mipmap/menu_feedback_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_feedback"
    />
```

this is my onMenuOpened() method:

```
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {

    if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null) {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
            try {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

I use the android studio, API 19, the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity,

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

I try to change the MainActivity extends Activity, and change the styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

but the result is the search button cannot display in the actionbar but display in the overflow Button, Fortunately, the menu item's icon has display, so I change the search button app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView", but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use the follow function instand of your onMenuOpened() method:

```
@Override
        protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
            if (menu != null) {
                if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
                    try {
                        Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                                "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        m.invoke(menu, true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
        }
```